# How can I limit the number of VMs (or other resources) that an Azure user can start?

Tags: azure

I have some contractors that need accounts in my Azure project but (sensibly) they request that we cap the amount of resources that their accounts can create in order to limit blast radius if their accounts were compromised.  How can I do that?

Comment: There's no such throttle in place, so you'd need to create the resources for them (which you can then provide access to via RBAC on individual resources within a resource group). This would give them the ability to use any resources you set up, but also limit things like *changing* resource setting (e.g. changing the size of a VM )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @David Makogon said, it would be a better way to create a resource group for them and deploy resources they want in that resource group and limit the access based on RBAC. But if this is dev or sandbox you try creating a DevTest Lab which gives you the ability to control the amount of vms and sizes they can use and also can give permissions to those who can only see and use resources they should be working on.

please refer the link below.
[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/lab-services/devtest-lab-concepts][1]

Hope this helps.